# Css --webkit-image-set() syntax doesn't work for Chrome

Tags: css, responsive-images

I want to use `.avif` and `.webp` for images on my website, remembering that I need provide fallback for unsupported browsers. Docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image/image-set()#using_image-set_to_provide_alternative_formats suggest that `-webkit-image-set` should help:

```css
background-image: url("/public/header-fallback.jpg");
background-image: -webkit-image-set(url('/public/header.avif') type('image/avif'), url('/public/header.webp') type('image/webp'), url('/public/header.jpg') type('image/jpeg'));
```

This works in Firefox (avif is skipped and webp is used) but Chrome gives me `Invalid property value` (entire style is ignored and 'header-fallback.jpg' is used). Why?

Comment: It looks like Chrome does not support types in (-webkit-)image-set yet; see section Browser Support here: https://dev.to/jsnkuhn/notes-on-image-set-with-type-55f0

Comment: As per https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=630597&can=2&q=css%20image-set (the bug linked in the article you linked), it 100% should be working for the prefixed version.  The bug is to remove the prefix from the (presumably functional) prefixed version.

Comment: If you skip `type`, it works on Chrome, but Safari & Edge will break. If you include `type`, Chrome is not ready for this yet. So we still need to wait.

Comment: First page you **always** check: https://caniuse.com/css-image-set *[Chrome] Has very limited support. Only url() is accepted as the image and only x is accepted as a resolution.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's seems that chrome not fully supports image-set

> our implementation has not been per the spec, as only URL values were accepted for the image, and only resolutions with 'x' as a unit were accepted.

[source](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5432024223449088)

To make it work with chrome try remove the type and add 1x instead

```
url('https://url.avif') 1x
```